# Regular Expression Union

Tags: regex

I am trying to have a union of regular expression such that it excludes *.log file and includes *.pl file by

```
^(.(?!(.log)))|^(.*\.pl)$
```

What would be the correct syntax for that?

Comment: simply use `^.*\.pl$` and other is automatically excluded. Do you really need to use excluded part in regex?

Comment: Actually I have 3 filters. I have files like test.xxx and test.xxx.log and test.pl. I am looking for a regex filter such that I get the result test.xxx and test.pl and exclude test.xxx.log. So I cannot only use ^.*\.pl$.

Comment: Okay, but why are `test.xxx` and `test.pl` included?  Is it because they contain the word `test`?  If it's only the extensions that matter (as you seem to be saying), I don't see the problem.  Just list the ones you want to include, and the exclusions will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Your lookahead would look like this.

```
^(?!.*\.log).*\.pl$
```

However, your regex is anchored so you could simply match the ones that end in `.pl`.

```
^.*\.pl$
```

To match all lines excluding the ones that end in `.log` assuming this is a possibility for what you need.

```
^(?!.*\.log).*$
```

Comment: Actually I have 3 filters. I have files like test.xxx and test.xxx.log and test.pl. I am looking for a regex filter such that I get the result test.xxx and test.pl and exclude test.xxx.log. So I cannot only use ^.*\.pl$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *exclude* the others, if it doesn't match it will not be in the output ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/fW3eI7/1)):

```
^.*?\.pl$
```

Answer (score 0):

Was not sure about the exact scenario in the question, but if you actually need to list all files with extensions, excluding the *.log and *.pl ones, you could use:

```
^.*\.(?!(pl|log))[^.]+$
```